# How to handle legacy app?

Tags: delphi

I have inherited a legacy app written in C++ (VS2003) MFC that was not updated in years. 
I have limited experience in C++, being mainly a Delphi developer. All other apps of the company are written in Delphi.

Going forward, I see a few choices:

1) Keep the app as is and become a C++ MFC developer. But I don't like the idea of using an outdated technology (MFC) for years to come, trying to keep up with new Windows versions and UI standards. It somehow feels like making several steps backwards and I don't think this is the best way to go (?)

2) Convert the app to any modern UI technology offered with C++ and become a C++ developer, but at least using modern technology. Might be a lot of work, not sure.

3) Rebuild the app from scratch in Delphi, where I will be a lot more productive thinking about the future. It's a lot more work right now, but it might pay off later.

Obviously, I personally prefer 3) but I would like to know from your experience which way is the best for the product.

It's a long term decision to make and I will have to stick with it, therefore I don't want to rush into one direction.

(I have intentionally not tagged this question as C++, trying to get answers from Delphi developers in similar situations)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all for your answers.
<strike>After learning that it is possible to switch to C++ Builder with a MFC application, this seems to be the best solution.
It combines the least amount of modifications to the current app with the possibility to go forward using the VCL for future GUI improvements.</strike>

**EDIT2:**

It's not possible to combine MFC and VCL in one app, therefore C++ Builder won't be an option. (thanks David for pointing this out)

Comment: Impossible to answer. Only you have enough knowledge to make the call. We'd just be guessing.

Comment: @David: Maybe I didn't phrase my question good enough, but I am not looking for the answer to my situation, I am looking for experiences that developers in similar situations have made to maybe find ideas that I don't see myself.

Comment: @Holgerwa That makes it not an ideal SO question.

Comment: @David: Yes, it's not a question with definite answers, but where else would you ask such a question if not on SO? And looking at some of the answers, I think I have found a good way to go (see Edit).

Comment: Your so called solution seems terrible to me! You can't mix MFC and VCL. If you are going to work with MFC you'd be far better off with Visual Studio.

Comment: @David: Of course, if it's not possible to combine MFC and VCL in one app, then this is no solution. I'm learning as I go, and before your comment, I didn't find any reference that said this is not possible for whatever reason.

Comment: @Holgerwa Well, it's really not possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard question to answer generically.  Can you provide any more information about your specific app?  What sort of technologies does it use?  How separated is the UI from underlying layers and logic?

Some general-ish points though:

- Rewriting an app is generally a bad idea, for the following reasons:

  - It's surprisingly hard to get an accurate idea of the requirements.  You're sure you know what it does (after all, it's right there in front of you!), but then you release your rewritten app and you get complains that functionality you didn't know was there is missing, that functionality is harder to access if you've changed something, etc.
  - It introduces bugs.  The code, especially if it's old, is full of bugfixes, tweaks, etc.  You will lose all that if you rewrite, especially if it's a different language and you can't reuse any code at all.
  - When using a different UI layer (MFC to something else) separating the UI can be very hard if the app wasn't written well in the first place.  You will probably end up doing a lot of refactoring, even if you don't do a complete rewrite and simply move from MFC to 'something else'.
- MFC is kept up to date (ish) - there is a [MFC Ribbon control](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vcsamplesmfc), for example, as well as [modern controls](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c17021) and [Windows 7 support](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Pat-Brenner-Visual-Studio-2010-MFC-and-Windows-7).  The least amount of work, probably, would be to upgrade to a modern version of Visual C++ and become a C++ developer.  However, you're quite right that MFC is an old technology and is unpleasant to use, not only because of its design, but also because modern form designers etc are great to use.
- You're a Delphi developer.  Without rewriting the entire thing, you could consider migrating to C++Builder.  Consider this:

  - You can use old versions of MFC with C++Builder.  I've never done this, since the VCL is miles ahead, but it's possible and there are a number of people who do it.  Check out [this forum](http://www.borlandtalk.com/c-builder-compatibility-with-mfc-vf187.html), for example.  (Credit for that link: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993017/c-builder-vs-delphi-vs-mfc).)
  - Once you have your app compiling and working with C++Builder, you can start migrating to the VCL.  As a Delphi developer you'll find using this, even with C++, very familiar.  It's the same form designer of course, and using it from C++ is pretty simple - it's a different language but code is often line-for-line translatable.  Everything you're used to (DFM files, units, event handlers, etc) all translate.
  - Not only that, but **Delphi code can be used in C++ projects**.  Just add the units to the project, and in your C++ code include the auto-generated `unitname.hpp` file.  [You can't (easily) use C++ code from Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html), but you could create new modules in Delphi and use them from C++.  As you do this, more and more of your app will slowly become Delphi code - ie, you don't need to rewrite in a different language all in one go.

**As a Delphi developer, I'd suggest going the C++Builder route.**  Get it working with MFC, and then migrate your windows to the VCL.  At that point, you could start rewriting modules in Delphi, or you may find yourself comfortable enough in C++ to continue developing as is.

**Edit:** I noticed in a reply above you like the idea above of making it a C++ DLL.  The link I gave a paragraph or two above of [using C++ object from Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) might be more applicable than I thought.  It would fit the RAD Studio (mix of C++ and Delphi) method as well.

Comment: -1: IMHO C++ Builder is a no-go. It can do a tiny fraction of what VC++ can do. Its code is less optimized. It has no 64 bit compiler yet. Trying to recompile VC++ code with it could be a nightmare.

Comment: @David: Thanks for your ideas. C++ Builder could be a good idea. Sounds interesting that there seem to be ways to use MFC code. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Idsandon: Can you give me a link or more information on why VC++ is so much bettern than C++ Builder? Up to now, I have seen the two as similar products (of course with little personal experience). A 64-bit compiler will not be an issue. But being able to use something like the VCL instead of MFC would be priceless.

Comment: There is little space here for a full discussion, but C++ Builder became a strange C++ aimed more or less at just building visual apps using the VCL. VC++ can build any kind of executable you may need in Windows (including drivers) while BC++ can't. Third party libraries may not support BC++ any longer. If your needs are fully covered by BC++, it could be what you're looking for, but trying to compile VC++ code is difficult, and requires a good knowledge to fix encounterd issues, and you need to retest everything fully. After all that, you learned a C++ tool with a too narrow horizon, IMHO.

Comment: @ldsandon: a downvote for "IMHO C++ Builder is a no go. It..."? Really? The [vote-down privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) is for "Whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect". C++ Builder can't link .sys files, sure, but I doubt Holgerwa wants to build a driver. It does allow use of Delphi code/VCL, ie you can "mix" and it's "strange" - why is that a problem here, but for .net languages it's a plus? I use it all the time, and it's very useful. Optimization I will agree though.

Comment: (I ran out of space for my reply :p) Recompiling the code in a different compiler could be tricky, you're right, and I didn't address that. It's still probably a lot easier than rewriting the whole thing in a different language. @Holgerwa, if you have third partly libraries you should check they're supported - boost has partial support, for example, and you'd want to check which bits you use.

Comment: @David M: try to recompile any recent (2003 onwards) C/C++ application written for VC++ with CBuilder. It's a nightmare. I know because we tried. We had RAD Studio and when we received by an external source an application written with VC++ we tried to compile it internally with CBuilder. We found so many issues it was cheaper to buy VC++ than spending the time to fix each of them. Did you ever try such a porting? I wrote "it's strange" not because it links the VCL, but because it became a somewhat "shrinked" C++ tool, while those looking for such tools usually have broader needs.

Comment: (run out of space too) From a developer's perspective may be better to learn C++ using VC++ than CBuilder, it will give him skills easier to "sell" one day. Moreover one would need a skilled C++ developer to iron out the issues he could find from VC++ to CBuilder. If one has at at the same time learn C++/MFC and port it to CBuilder he will surely have a hard time. If the OP was a skilled CBuilder developer it could be a solution (although a risky one IMHO), but in its actual situation IMHO is really a dangerous attempt. I tried to remove the downvote, which could be excessive, but couldn't.

Answer (score 5):

In general everything depends on how complex the application's logic is and what is the projected life time of the application. If it requires maintenance for another 20 years, then 
I'd rewrite the UI in Delphi and move the business logic into C++ DLL (for beginning and possibly rewrite it in Delphi either). Then it can turn that the application can be maintained this way for another 10 years and relatively easily ported to other platforms if needed (less work would be required).

Comment: It will have to be maintained / improved for many years, if not decades. The app logic is very complex, and it's also not the main problem, because it works fine. The GUI is the problem, at least for now. Turning it into a C++ DLL sound interesting!

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the app as is, tying you to MFC, is likely not very productive - You'll need to learn a GUI toolkit you'll most likely never use for something else (Delphi *is* great for GUI, MFC doesn't even come close IMO), in addition to a new language.

That leaves you with the choice of rewriting it in a somewhat unfamiliar language using an unfamiliar GUI toolkit, which'll take a lot more time than rewriting it in a familiar language using a familiar GUI toolkit. So you should just get started porting this to Delphi.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting C++ code in Delphi isn't as easy as you think. A better way to rewrite it is by just redesigning it from scratch, without looking at the old code. Feel free to look how the old application worked, so you can rebuild it. Just don't look at the code. That way, you should get a more modern result.
Of course, if you use the RAD Studio then you have both the C++ as Delphi compiler, thus it should be able to continue to develop the C++ application, although this means you have to learn C++. Then again, any good programmer should be able to just move to another programming language and learn to use it within 2 weeks to a month. C++ can be complex but still, learning C++ and then maintaining the legacy app should take a lot less time than a complete rewrite.
Do keep in mind that any generic C++ application should be able to be compiled for any platform, although the MFC will probably restrict this to just Windows. Still, it's a language that has an even better backwards compatibility than Delphi!

But to keep in mind, will this app run on a different platform in the future? Should it become a .NET application? Or run on Linux? Should it support tablet computers? Android? Your choices today might be outdated again in two years. And since Delphi has a bit uncertain future right now, mostly because C#/.NET became so popular, you might have a more safe bet with C++. Try to replace the MFC libraries with a more modern UI technology, preferably one that's available for multiple platforms, and think very, very well about the future usages of this application.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend

> 1) Keep the app as is and become a C++ MFC developer. But I don't like the idea of using an outdated technology (MFC) for years to come, trying to keep up with new Windows versions and UI standards. It somehow feels like making several steps backwards and I don't think this is the best way to go (?)

Since MFC is well supported and keeps going with the time. MFC is also a what-you'd-call **intrusive framework**, meaning that the framework dependencies are usually not easily refactored. (The author of CPPDepend published some nice stats on that IIRC, but I can certainly vouch for this from my own experience with large MFC applications).

If you're gonna rewrite to any modern UI framework, **don't code the UI in C++** (judging from the fact that Delphi is an option, it is not about realtime visualizations or something like that).

<strike>*(I'll unask the unasked question here: I you're gonna rewrite, XXXXXXXXXXXXX?)*</strike> **please gentle(wo)men, let's not do the flame**

Comment: why Delphi: I use Delphi since it's beginning, never had any problems with it, all our other apps are already written in Delphi. It seems to be a good choice to use one language for everthing, if possible.

Comment: I'll ask the other unasked question. Why NOT Delphi?

Comment: @Seve: Because getting good Delphi developers is hard. C++, Java and C# developers are a dime a dozen. Also, it might sometime be necessary to port this application to a non-Windows platform, but I think that's a minor issue because most likely it will again be a complete rewrite anyway.

Comment: Finding good C++ developers is not easy at all. Java and C# use curly braces, but they are not nor C nor C++. Those spending the time to learn all the intricacies of C++ are not that many, and usually works on more complex projects. And finding **good** Delphi developers could be very challenging, being able to drop a couple of controls on a form and writing three events doesn't make a good developer.

Answer (score 1):

In general I'd say:

- If it's a tiny tool application, and it takes just a couple of days to do a full rewrite: go for it.  Don't waste your time creating dll wrappers or to interface with the existing code in other ways. Just do a full rewrite and be done with it.
- Otherwise: you'll probably be making changes in one specific area of the application at the time only. Unless the code is a complete spaghetti, you could even get away with making some local changes without fully understanding the implementation details of the rest of the code.

In any case, you need to invest some time into understanding the application and its language + frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a great opportunity to learn C++ and MFC. Take advantage of it. When Delphi goes astray you will have the required knowledge to keep on coding with a language that won't go away so easily, and you can even broaden your development horizons to areas Delphi (and C++ Builder) will never reach. MFC is no more outdated than the VCL is (although I agree the original design is worse).
Good UI programming has nothing to do with the ability to drop controls on a form visually. Many great applications are not built that way. Actually, trying to rewrite it in Delphi could bring you issue in the future, as long as Embarcadero delivers slowly, and without a credible roadmap.

Comment: @Idsandon: My concern up to now was that it is not a great opportunity to learn C++ and MFC, but that it might be a waste of time since nobody really uses it anymore and to go this route would be a dead end for the future. Of course I'd be glad to learn that MFC is still up to date and used even for new projects.

Comment: Are you sure "nobody uses it really anymore"? First, C++ is here to stay, I would be much more worried about Delphi than C++. And although MS is pushing .NET frameworks to customers needing a RAD tool, MFC is still being upgraded and used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336130.aspx

Comment: @Idsandon: It was only my first impression that MFC is old and not in use anymore. Thanks for clearing that up. Staying with MFC might be a way to go after all...

Answer (score 0):

Does the app come with a descent amount of automated tests? If not you're pretty much stuck with option 1 and hope for the best. If there are many tests you can do a lot more with the code without breaking all kinds of things you didn't know were there.